# Create Area or Polygon based upon a Series of points

Tags: qgis, sql

i have a large list of points that i would like to merge to create an Polygon based upon an attribute.
Essentially an area that encompasses all points.

```
x   |   y   |   attr
____________________
1   |   1   |   One
2   |   2   |   One
1   |   2   |   One
2   |   1   |   One
1.5 |   1.5 |   One
```

in the above example i would expect to see a box around the fifth point with an attribute of One

my data is held in SQL Server and i could either export this into qGIS to resolve or solve within SQL.

is there any way of re-solving this, or does the issue of generating a Link between the 5th and 1st point prevent this?

Comment: i think that the described polygon here is self intersecting, do you need the have the convexe hull of the points to form the polygon ?

Comment: i think you just mentioned about three things i do not understand

Comment: Given your points are not necessarily in order, how could you possibly know what the right order is, for an an arbitrary collection of points? Alternatively, try to describe why the fifth point is not part of the "box"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fTools plug-in tool "convex hull" to create polygons based on the attribute field.